# How to force the Detail page to move right with the Master page on iPad in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When using an iPhone, the Detail page automatically moves to the right with the Master page when the hamburger/menu icon (☰) is clicked.

**Before clicked:**

[image: portrait_pefore]
[image: landscape_before]

**After clicked:** (As you can see, the entire Detail page moves with the Master)

[image: portrait_after]
[image: landscape_after]

---

However with an iPad, when you click the Hamburger icon, the Master page moves right, but goes on top of the Detail page (and so the Detail page doesn't move right with it)

**Before clicked**

[image: portrait_before]
[image: landscape_before]

**After clicked** (As you can see here, the Detail page does not move right with the Master page. This can be identified by looking at the "Home" Title, and how it does not change position from before to after)

[image: portrait_after]
[image: landscape_after]

---

**Question**
My question would be how to recreate this effect (experienced on iPhone) on iPad. The main reason why I wish to do this, is because of the ShadowEffect I have attached to the NavigationPage.Appearing.

This moves with the navPage, and so on iPads, it is hidden. I also use the MasterBehavior.Popover enum for the MasterBehavior property.

Thanks for your time, Daniel

Comment: I know you want to achieve this effect on iPad just as it's on iPhone. But these are two different devices. iPad has larger size enough to display its content so that it is no need to reduce the detail view's size. Moreover you can see the native view in the system app of ios(i.e. Settings). iPhone and iPad has two different styles to display the items.

Comment: @Land I need this effect because of the fact that the ShadowEffect doesn't work on iPad, and just looks awful... How do all of the other apps do it so easily and all look the same? Could you please take a look at https://github.com/jdehlin/Xamarin-Sidebar for me?

Comment: @Land Okay, so I got it right with the Xamarin-Sidebar, but now when I see it in action, it only allows for the hamburger menu icon to be on the right... How on earth do other apps do it then?!

Comment: It may be by design what Xamarin-Sidebar's author want it to be, but I'm not sure. We can also change its style by modifying its source code. Every effect can be achieved if we want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using master detail page then you can't change the behavior in iPhone even if you change the behavior to popover it will perform same as you shown in the picture. If you want master details page behavior same on every platform you have to use some other libraries Like **[this Slide over kit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit)**.

Comment: This seems like a great option! Thanks so mu for making me aware about it, but I don't think it is the look I want to go for. I would really like to have the shadow effect as seen above, and I have found another resource (https://github.com/jdehlin/Xamarin-Sidebar) but I don't know how to implement it just for iOS, do you have any ideas (I have xamarin.forms)? I would really appreciate if you edited this answer with more info on that :).

Comment: Okay, so I got it right with the Xamarin-Sidebar, but now when I see it in action, it only allows for the hamburger menu icon to be on the right... How on earth do other apps do it then?! @Mayur Kerasiya - I just wanted to add, that the SlideOverKit also doesn't allow for the menu icon to be on the left

Comment: I have added toolbar item in detail page so it displayed right side automatically and on click of that showed menu page.  Note:You have to add toolbar item on every details page which are in menu page list

Comment: Yes, but you can only add a toolbar item on the right, not left...

Comment: in xamarin forms all the toolbar items displayed on right side for that you have to create you own toolbar and I prefer to create view on every Content page and hide the navigation bar. ** For creating your own view using stacklayout you have to maintain height of that view **

Comment: Can this be also done on Android?